# How to sort list based off of a join to another table

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a table that needs to be sorted alphabetically by names that aren't actually contained in the table **in sqlalchemy**.  Only codes representing the names are in the table.  Like so...

Table 1:

```
row  code  month   value
1    A     201501  50
2    Z     201501  100
3    CO    201501  200
4    VA    201502  300
5    C     201502  300
```

Table 2:

```
row  code  name
1    A     Apple
2    C     Cascade
3    CO    Colorado
4    VA    Virginia
```

I need to sort **Table 1** the following:

- month
- name (found in Table 2)

What is the best technique to achieve these sorting results when the sorting occurs on value not inherent in the table.  I can't send the joined product of Table 1 and Table 2.  Although, I can join them temporarily and remove the 'name' column if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.* FROM TABLE1 T1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON
T1.code = T2.code
ORDER BY T1.month, T2.name
```

Use `T2.[columnName]` to select data from `TABLE2` (if needed)

Comment: apologies.  I meant to only post this in the sqlalchemy area because I need to use it to solve this issue.  I added it to the question.  That said - thanks for the response.  I may need to implement this in sql in the end (but hopefully not).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT t1.* FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2 WHERE t1.code = t2.code ORDER BY t2.name;
```

This will *join* the tables. But it will return only the content from table `t1`.